# How to identify dhcp ip change?

Tags: shell, scripting, dhcp

Unfortunately, I don't have the control over DHCP of the network. If I have to ssh into my box, I need to know the ip address. I dont have the root access to my box too :( .  I want to write some script which would mail me in case my ip has changed. Is there a better way to do this than writing a while loop and checking the ip?

Comment: while loop, with `sleep 300` sounds as good as you can do. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

DynDns is probably what you need.

Comment: This isn't going to help if the OP doesn't have root on the box.